# Safe-dereferencing project properties in groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I learned, that it is best practice to always check for having the actual referenced value. [From here](https://dzone.com/articles/groovys-smooth-operators) I have the hint to to do this like that:

> This is especially useful to avoid null pointer exceptions in a chained expression. For example,
>
> ```
> String location = map.getLocation().getXandYCoordinates();
> ```
>
> might yield a null pointer exception. But using the safe navigation operator if either `map`, or the result of `map.getLocation()` are null
>
> ```
> String location = map?.getLocation()?.getXandYCoordinates();
> ```
>
> location will just be set as null. So, no null pointer exception is thrown.

But this will only help against an existing variable (say `map`) being null, not against a non-existing or non-set variable.

Example:

```
println "Safe dereferencing junk: " + project?.junk
```

where there is no `junk` inside the `settings.gradle` etc. → returns:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
...

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
> Could not get unknown property 'junk' for root project 'test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

How can this be improved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually using the `hasProperty` method:

```
if (hasProperty('junk')) 
    println junk 
else
    println "There is no junk."
```

You can also use a `Closure` to do this automatically:

```
Closure getPropSafe = { // it -> //For one parameter the "param ->" syntax is optional
    //println 'Has it the property ' + it + '? -> 'project.hasProperty(it)
    if (project.hasProperty(it)) {
        it = project.properties."${it}" //Dereference
        return it //"return" is needed
    }
    //You could also modify this to do somethign in the else block, otherwise it implicitly returns null.
}

//Then call it with the String name of the property like this:
project.ext.sayHello = 'Hej!!'
println "Own getPropSafe dereferencing junk: " + getPropSafe('junk') //gives null
println 'Own getPropSafe saying Hello: ' + getPropSafe('sayHello') //gives "Hej!!"
```